# Python: joining two lists

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

How to combine two lists by alternatively taking elements. For example: given the two lists ['a','b','c'] and [1, 2, 3, 4], the function should return [a, 1, b, 2, c, 3, 4]

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
b = ['a','b','c'] 

result = [item for sublist in zip(b,a) for item in sublist]

print result
```

Comment: swap `zip(a,b)` for `zip(b,a)`